# How to update empty column in Sqlite (Android)

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I'm sure there are lots of similar question but my context is kinda different.

So i'm working on an android app and i'm inserting data into a table. Let's say the table name is user with columns firstname and lastname which are of type text.

I run an insert function to insert a row into the table but with information for just firstname. So firstname is inserted and lastname is empty. Now here come the problem.

When I try to update the column lastname, it doesn't work. I don't know if it's cos it empty or null.

My update code looks something like

```
 int result = db.update(TABLE_USER, contentvalue, "_id= someValue", null);
```

Result is usually 0.
Contentvalue contains lastname and I can guarantee it's not empty.

I don't know if during the first insert, it's mandatory to set the value of the last to null or empty and not let the db handle that cos it works if I do. Any suggestion is appreciated and i'ld like to know why it doesn't work too. Thanks

Comment: does your table have the column `_id` ? did you debug/log the value `someValue`? is it correct?  did you make sure that the row is actually inserted? otherwise you will be updating a row that does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with

```
int result = database.update(TABLE_USERS, contentValues, "firstname = ?" , new String[] {firstname});
```

Answer (score 1):

No during insert, it is not mandatory to fill all columns. If you want to update a value, then you can take reference from my method. After creating this method only you have to call this method by object of dbhelper class.

```
public void updateData(String id, String eventname, String strdate, String strtime, String enddate, String endtime) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_EVENTNAME,eventname);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_STARTDATE,strdate);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_STARTTIME,strtime);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_ENDDATE, enddate);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_ENDTIME,endtime);

    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, COLUMN_ID+"="+id, null);
}
```

Make accepted if this will work....thanks in advance

Comment: But you see, this is technically what i've been doing with no results

Comment: you are updating the column value in table so how can you store result.if you want to see updated result then again you have to write query like **SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME**  then you'll see updated result.

Comment: int result returns 1 if true and 0 if false. Thanks how u know if an update went through or not.

Comment: hey make accepted if you got reference from this. @MueyiwaMosesIkomi